# React npm run build shows 404 not found in hosting subdirectory

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, devops

I am trying to upload a react js, node js application to my hosting server in a subdomain folder. I created a build folder by npm run build and uploaded on hosting subfolder but the page is showing blank. Please, can anyone help?

Comment: More details are required such as, how are you running the application, what are the node configuration to access the web pages and whether there is a reverse proxy infront of the nodejs server

Comment: yes it is running well now, but node api's are not working and showing error. I used proxy for node api connect and npm run all for react node running concurrently. It is working on locally perfectly but on hosting server not working.